# get the position in a table

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have this .I am able to drag where ever I want.Is there a way to create another table that I will get the positions of each image where it goes?(only the position).An example,as you can see there are positions 1 until 24.In position 12 I have red images.In position 24 I have black images.What I was to do is if I drag from position 12 the image with number a to the position,I want to put this value  lets say in the slot 11, then when I did that drag it will be creating  a new table like and will write (11,a).Conclusion, 11 will be the position and a the image i transfer.Can that happen?I am trying so far with not a result..thanks in advance.

**edited:** you drag an image in position lets say 5,a next drag you do with the same image you go to (1,a ) then you can not drag anymore that image -(if that can happen )

Comment: this is the link https://jsfiddle.net/h5b6rofx/?fbclid=IwAR2bh40J88fUcCwXNW9AqUZ_G75zFrK2Iqh4ilH6lApyufYFZvB8HiJjRao

Comment: I couldn't uploaded on the code

Comment: so on every drag you need to put entry in another table ?

Comment: yes exactly that I want(if it can be to stop the drag for second time the same image,example i move a on a spot,then i move it again ,i can't for 3 time- if that can happen it will be good too)

Comment: next time you cannot drag same image ? it should be fixed ? what do you mean by `i can't for `3 time-..`? Also add this in your asked question as well

Comment: @Swati if that  is possible (I don't know if that can be happen)

Comment: I mean you drag an image in position lets say 5,a next drag you do with the same image you go to (1,a ) then you can not drag anymore that image -(if that can happen )

Comment: There are two image with `a` black and red are they treated as 1 ?  because you say if `a` is drag two time then it should not allow to drag again but there are two images  both should not allow to drag ?

Comment: no they are not treated as one image!there are different images-if you want change rename it.make the black ab from a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much easier when you decouple the data from the UI - meaning that a dataset is being processed in the background while the images are dragged around.

In the following little snippet I'll attempt to do that with your case. The items keep track if they can be dragged or not.

The `items` are now filled with only 4 images, but you can add any number of images there - they can be handled as separate items. **The only thing to pay attention to: the `id`s of the items must be unique.**

```js
const items = [{
    id: 0,
    dataid: "a",
    type: "red",
    src: "https://i.imgur.com/ZEZLSOo.png",
    draggable: 2,
    position: 12,
    alt: "Norway",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    dataid: "b",
    type: "red",
    src: "https://i.imgur.com/ZEZLSOo.png",
    draggable: 2,
    position: 12,
    alt: "Norway",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    dataid: "a",
    type: "black",
    src: "https://i.imgur.com/dL3J8XS.jpeg",
    draggable: 2,
    position: 13,
    alt: "Norway",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    dataid: "b",
    type: "black",
    src: "https://i.imgur.com/dL3J8XS.jpeg",
    draggable: 2,
    position: 13,
    alt: "Norway",
  }
]

const itemHTML = (item) => {
  return `
    <span
      class="event"
      data-id="${ item.dataid }"
      draggable="${ !!item.draggable }"
    >
     ${ item.dataid } <img
        data-imgid="${ item.id }"
        src="${ item.src }"
        class="b"
        alt="${ item.alt }"
        style="width: 30%;"
      />
    </span>
  `
}

// redrawing the table based on item attributes
const updateTable = (table, items) => {
  $(table).find('td').each(function(i, e) {
    let html = ''
    const filtered = items.filter(({
      position
    }) => position - 1 === i)
    if (filtered.length) {
      filtered.forEach(item => {
        html += itemHTML(item)
      })
    } else {
      html = !$(e).parent().index() ? i + 1 : 24 - $(e).index()
    }
    e.innerHTML = html
  })
}

updateTable('#targetTable tbody', items)

const dragrowHTML = ({
  id,
  to
}) => {
  return `<tr><td>${ id }</td><td>${ to }</td></tr>`
}

$(function() {
  initDragAndDrop();
});

function clearDragAndDrop() {
  $('.event').off();
  $('#targetTable td').off('dragenter dragover drop');
}

function initDragAndDrop() {
  $('.event').on('dragstart', function(event) {
    const itemid = event.target.getAttribute('data-imgid')
    var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
    //add dat-attr and class from where to remove
    dt.setData('id', itemid);
  });

  $('.event').on('dragend', function(event) {
    clearDragAndDrop();
    initDragAndDrop();
  });

  // updated event handling
  $('#targetTable td').on('dragenter dragover drop', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.type === 'drop') {
      const itemid = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('id');
      const item = items.find(({
        id
      }) => id == itemid)
      // if item is draggable
      if (item && item.draggable) {
        // calculate position
        item.position = ($(event.target).parent().index() * $(event.target).parent().children().length) + ($(event.target).index() + 1)
        // update table
        updateTable('#targetTable tbody', items)
        // update item's draggable property
        $('#dragtable tbody').append(dragrowHTML({
          id: item.id,
          to: item.position
        }))
        item.draggable--
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td span {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #09C;
  font-weight: bold;
}

img {
  padding: 10px;
}

#dragtable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#dragtable th,
#dragtable td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="targetTable" class="b" border="10" bordercolor="blue" id="myT">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> 1</td>
      <td> 2</td>
      <td> 3</td>
      <td> 4</td>
      <td> 5</td>
      <td> 6</td>
      <td> 7</td>
      <td> 8</td>
      <td> 9</td>
      <td> 10</td>
      <td> 11</td>
      <td> 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 24</td>
      <td> 23</td>
      <td> 22</td>
      <td> 21</td>
      <td> 20</td>
      <td> 19</td>
      <td> 18</td>
      <td> 17</td>
      <td> 16</td>
      <td> 15</td>
      <td> 14</td>
      <td> 13</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="dragtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>TO</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: hello, but it doesn't pass on a new table the drag..that was the basic I wanted thing to do

Comment: @e.l OK, I see. I didn't understand your problem fully then, I focused on toggling `draggable` behavior

Comment: yes ,nice work ,but the real problem is to pass those drags (so after I will put it in mysql - thats another story ^^ )

Comment: @e.l they are shown in another table now - I edited the snippet